# Android-SQLite: the constructor DBHelper is undefined

Tags: android, sql, database, constructor, undefined

basicly, I'm trying to show the result of a listview (created with QSLite)but in the class CourseDetails for extract a element of the listview resulting, have this problem:

"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The constructor DBHelper(CourseDetails) is undefined    CourseDetails.java  /MariposaTrainingMobile/src/com/mariposatraining/courses    line 31 Java Problem"

I'm using a DBHelper class for this, but i don't know why the program send me that error, and dont give a solution for the problem, the code of my DBHelper class is the next:

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private String sql;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql= " CREATE TABLE courses (" + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " title TEXT, " + " instructor TEXT, " + " length TEXT, " + " rating TEXT, " + " topic TEXT, " + " subject TEXT, " + "description TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);        
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS courses");
    onCreate(db);       
}


public void insertCourses()
{
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Enabling Freedom...', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 4.82', 'Topic: Creating a Prosthetic Environment ', 'Subject:Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Description: Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Interdisciplinary Care Planning', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 4.7', 'Topic: Interdisciplinary Care Planning', 'Subject:Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Description: Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Culture Change: Creating A Climate Of Care...', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Culture Change ', 'Subject:Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Description: Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Medical Records Documentation', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Medical Records Documentation ', 'Subject:Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Description: Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Census Challenges', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 4.45', 'Topic: Creative Solutions to Drive Census ', 'Subject:Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Description: Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Fall Prevention: Reducing Fall Related Injuries', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Guidelines for Health Care Providers ', 'Subject:Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Description: Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Meaningful Engagement', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Creating The Failure Free Activity Program ', 'Subject:Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Description: Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Dementia and Delirium', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 4.69', 'Topic: The Importance of Accurate Diagnosis and Treatment ', 'Subject:Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Description: Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Behavior Management', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Using Root Cause ', 'Subject:Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Description: Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('Communication: Powerful Tools For...', 'Instructor: Keith Savell', 'length: 60', 'Rating: 5', 'Topic: Powerful Tools For Communicating With Residents ', 'Subject:Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Description: Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

public ArrayList<Courses> getCourses()
{
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    sql = "SELECT title, instructor, length, rating, topic, subject, description FROM courses";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    ArrayList<Courses> courses = new ArrayList<Courses>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Courses oCourses=new Courses();
        oCourses.title=cursor.getString(0);
        oCourses.instructor=cursor.getString(1);
        oCourses.length=cursor.getString(2);
        oCourses.rating=cursor.getString(3);
        oCourses.topic=cursor.getString(4);
        oCourses.subject=cursor.getString(5);
        oCourses.description=cursor.getString(6);
        courses.add(oCourses);          
    }

    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return courses;

}}
```

and my class CourseDetails for show the element selected:

```
public class CourseDetails extends Activity {
 protected TextView tTitle;
protected TextView tInstructor;
protected TextView tLength;
protected TextView tRating;
protected TextView tTopic;
protected TextView tSubject;
protected TextView tDescription;

protected int courseId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_details);

    courseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("COURSE_ID", 0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = **(new DBHelper(this))**.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.title, emp.instructor, emp.length, emp.rating, emp.topic, emp.subject, emp.description, mgr.title managerTitle, mgr.instructor managerInstructor FROM courses emp LEFT OUTER JOIN courses mgr ON emp.rating = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 

            new String[]{""+courseId});

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            tTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTitle);
            tTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            tInstructor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tInstructor);
            tInstructor.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instructor")));

            tLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tLength);
            tLength.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("length")));

            tRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tRating);
            tRating.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("rating")));

            tTopic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTopic);
            tTopic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("topic")));

            tSubject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tSubject);
            tSubject.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject")));

            tDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDescription);
            tDescription.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

    }

}}
```

really would appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. You're calling a constructor:

```
(new DBHelper(this))
```

which means the constructor signature should look like this:

```
public DBHelper(Context context)
```

But the only constructor you've defined is this one:

```
public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
    int version)
```

You need to call the constructor with the correct arguments, or add a new constructor with whichever arguments you want.

Comment: could tell me how I should properly call the constructor without recreate it? thank you very much!

Comment: You need to supply all the missing parameters. See the documentation for what the parameters mean: http://goo.gl/1eGr4

Answer (score 1):

You're creating DBHelper like this:

```
new DBHelper(this)
```

Where "this" is a CourseDetails object.

However, the only constructor you supply is

```
public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

Comment: but really do not know how to define properly the builder with the DHBHelper already created without creating a new one, thanks a lot for your help..